# Flex + SQLite + LMS

Tags: database, apache-flex, sqlite, moodle

Is it possible to use SQLite as a read-only database in a Flex project made to work in a SCORM-compatible Learning Management System?

It says at the SQLite site that their database is serverless. Does it mean that I am able to include it into a zip-package and import it into the Moodle after that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, SQLite can work in [readonly mode](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html). It should work for you, however standard SQLite cannot access compressed (zipped) database - it must be present on disk in conventional, uncompressed format.

If you want your database to be compressed (and optionally encrypted) natively, you should consider using [CEROD](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/cerod.html) - commercial SQLite extension by SQLite author.

Comment: I suppose that after I zip my project, the LMS unzips it, thus there shouldn't be any problem with compression. Anyway, it is worth a try! Thank you!